# How to get a DatePeriod with "every first thursday in month"?

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I'm having two `DateTime`-objects:

```
$start = new DateTime('first thursday of June 2012');
$end   = new DateTime('2012-12-31');
```

I need a `DatePeriod` that contains all first Thursdays of the months between this two dates. When using

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
```

This only adds 1 month without respecting the condition "first thursday".

Also something like this does not work:

```
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month first thursday');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've struggled with this the last two hours - as soon as I posted it here I got the solution.
I only had to change the DateInterval string to "first thursday of next month".

```
$start = new DateTime('first thursday of June 2012');
$end   = new DateTime('2012-12-31');

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('first thursday of next month');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
```

Works! DateTime rocks ;-)

Comment: lol ... i was just about to post that ...... how come you knew that i was thinking